# Does rsync delete files on the destination that were deleted from the sending side?

Tags: rsync, backup

Does rsync delete files from the destination if they were deleted from the source?

For example, say in the source /home/me I have three files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

Now, I run the command `rsync -v /home/me/ user@ip.address:/home/backup` and it copies files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` to `/home/backup`.

The contents of `/home/backup` are now

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

If I were to delete `a.txt` from `/home/me`, would `a.txt` get deleted from `/home/backup` the next time I run rsync, is there an option I need to specify or is it just completely impossible?

If there are any alternatives to rsync that do this, they are welcome as well.

Side note: I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76739/rsync-delete-files-on-receiving-side-that-were-deleted-on-sending-side-but-do%20and) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/asking-rsync-to-delete-files-on-the-receiving-side-that-dont-exist-on-the-sendi) relating to this topic, but I couldn't exactly understand or see how it was exactly related to the question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Only if you… select one of the delete options. See [`man rsync`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) for more information, but here is an excerpt:

```
--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
--delete-before         receiver deletes before xfer, not during
--delete-during         receiver deletes during the transfer
--delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
--delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not during
--delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

There is more detailed information for these options further down the `man` page.

Comment: Just to confirm, this means that if I select --delete, rsync would delete  files from the destination that were deleted from the source, making the source and destination an exact mirror?

Comment: Yes, but just have a read of the man page! There are caveats and hints, including running it with `--dry-run`.